# I am solving a question on hacker rank I don't know how to read stdinput

Tags: python, stdin

I'm not able figure out why it is showing an error when I am trying to solve this problem on hackerrank despite my solution is right. I am not able to understand STDIN and STDOUT. Please refer to the picture which I have attached:

[image]

```
import sys

def triangle(my_string = sys.stdin.readline()):
    # first parse the standard input which is in form of string
    char = []
    
    for i in str(my_string):
        char.append(i)
                
    # is all the sides of the triangle are equal it is equilateral triangle
    if char[0] == char[1] == char[2]:
        print("Equilateral")
    
    # if two sides are equal it is an Isosoleces triangle 
    elif (char[0] == char[1]) or (char[1] == char[2]) or (char[2] == char[0]):
        print("Isosceles")
    
    # if all three sides are different it is an  Noneofthese 
    else:
        print("None of these")
```

Comment: You are never calling `triangle`

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works. You had to convert the input into integers.
Also you are ignoring the spaces in the input. Hope it helps.

```
import sys

my_string = input()
# first parse teh standard input wich is in form of string
splits = my_string.split(sep=' ')
value1 = int(splits[0])
value2 = int(splits[1])
value3 = int(splits[2])

# is all the sides of the triangle are equal it is eqaulatral triangle
if value1 == value2 == value3:
    print("Equilateral")

# if two sides are eqaul it is an isoleces triangle
elif (value1 == value2) or (value2 == value3) or (value3 == value1):
    print("Isosceles")

# if all three sides are diffrent it is an  Noneofthese
else:
    print("None of these")
```